# Force a play framework dependency

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I'm trying Play Framework 2.3.8 (Java) to use a specific sbt import.

To the build.sbt I've added:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.1"
```

The class I'm using from this library is using play's core dependency:
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcode:4.0.1

I can't seem to force play to use the newer version. The problem that I am experiencing is with the class:

```
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

The 4.0.1 version doesn't support the consume method in:

```
EntityUtils.consume(entity)
```

while version 4.4.1 does.

How do I force Play Framework to use the 4.4.1 version?
I've tried to delete it but play re-downloads the older version when I build.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.1"
```

See more details in the [Overriding a version](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version) section of the Library Management docs.